# Factory in typescript with a generic argument

Tags: typescript, generics, factory

I'm trying to implement a factory in typescript that returns a generic type.
Already figured out that I need to pass the type as the first argument, and setting it's type to a CTOR signature (`new () => T` in this example).
The problem begins when I want to pass a generic type to the factory - I get an error saying:
`Value of type 'typeof G' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?(2348)`.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Here is a simplified version of the problem:

```js
// Generic class
class G<T>{}
// Standard non generic
class B{}

function make<T>(t: new () => T){
    return new t()
}
// Works
make(B)
// Value of type 'typeof G' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?(2348)
make(G<number>)
```

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/FAehAIHEFMDtoE4EsDG4UBsCGBnHxNccoAeAFQD4BvAX1AgGUAXLWAEywTfFgHtZwAcziJUBbHnAAhWsGAAzAK6wUTJP3ABbLAGto5CgAomALh7QA7uEMBKcAF4K4MjarBwH8AmhNFCAfBWTLbAdGDgAOq8CDr42nqGUjb04ABqWBiK0OC88uBMAJ4ADtkA5IUluVCl4EjEfEzoGdgARhjQAHTgACJI3AW8ilrQrPm8tSqZbGWBpQD8hgBMAMwALAAcyfHQhpAksIqaLYgUNkA) to the above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you set the generic in the wrong place. In `make(value)`, `value` should be runnable code without any TypeScript definition. So the call `make(G<number>)` is false because you can't call a TypeScript generic as a parameter.

To define the generic, you need to write it before the parenthesis:

```js
make<G<number>>(G)
```

So here, `G<number>` is the type that you give and `G` is the 'valid' runnable code.

Have a look at the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/FAehAIHEFMDtoE4EsDG4UBsCGBnHxNccoAeAFQD4BvAX1AgGUAXLWAEywTfFgHtZwAcziJUBbHnAAhWsGAAzAK6wUTJP3ABbLAGto5CgAomALh7QA7uEMBKcAF4K4MjarBwH8AmhNFCAfBWTLbAdGDgAOq8CDr42nqGUjb04ABqWBiK0OC88uBMAJ4ADtkA5IUluVCl4EjEfEzoGdgARhjQAHTgACJI3AW8ilrQrPm8tSqZbGWBpQD8hgBMAMwALAAcyfH6kCSwipotiBRGkDZAA).